# How to change cache context array for home page

Tags: caching

I have Drupal setup using multisite so that the contents vary with sub domain. I need to use 'url.site' in 'cache context'. But cache context array contains 'url.site' only for node pages. In home page it contains:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => languages:language_interface 
   [1] => theme 
   [2] => user.permissions 
)
```

I think overriding function `getCacheableRenderArray()` with the below code will fix the issue.

```
if (!in_array('url.site', $elements['#cache']['contexts'])) {
  $elements['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.site';
}
```

How can I override the above mentioned array values using Drupal's default method?